# Proper way to return multiple variable from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning more about the inner workings of javascript objects and came across an example where multiple variables were returned from the object:

```
var squareGrid = function(width, n, z) {
        width = width || 1;
        n = n || 4;
        var z = z || width / 2.0;

        var edges = [],
            pts = [];

        var step = width / n;
        for (var u = 0; u < n; u++) {
            var u_added = u * n * 4;
            for (var v = 0; v < n; v++) {
                var delta = u_added + 4 * v;

                var t_v = step * (v - n / 2);
                var t_u = step * (u - n / 2);

                pts.push([t_v, t_u, z]); // top left
                pts.push([t_v, t_u + step, z]); // top right
                pts.push([t_v + step, t_u + step, z]); // bottom right
                pts.push([t_v + step, t_u, z]); // bottom left

                edges.push([delta + 0, delta + 1]);
                edges.push([delta + 1, delta + 2]);
                edges.push([delta + 2, delta + 3]);
                edges.push([delta + 3, delta + 0]);
            }

        }
        return {
            edges: edges,
            pts: pts
        };
    }
```

In this case, in order to return both `edges` and `points`, it looks like there are key-value pairs being returned where the keys and values are the same thing. Is this method necessary or can the following just be done?

`return{ edges, pts}};`

Comment: Not in ES5, unless you want an array.

Comment: @SLaks Can I just do this then: ```return{ edges, pts}};``` ? And if so, when should I use which method?

Comment: JavaScript objects don't *return* anything. In your example, the function returns an object. `return { edges, pts }` is actually valid ES6 and is just the short form for `return { edges: edges, pts: pts }`. But it's not clear to me what exactly your question is. *"it looks like there are key-value pairs being returned where the keys and values are the same thing"* They are not. The property name and the *variable name* are just the same. The property name is the string "edges" but the value is an array of something.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be returning an object where the keys would be edges and the values would be the return value of edges.

```
x = squareGrid(400, 2, 5)

x.edges
// edges
x.pts
//pts
```

You could do something like:  data = callfunction() -> return [edges, points]

```
data[0]
// edges
data[1]
//points
```

** Correction **
when keys are stored in a js hash it serializes the key before attempting to store the value

what would get stored is the serialized version of the array as the key, with the value being the array

Comment: how is the key value of edges different from the return value. If edges is an array, than any time "edges" is referenced, it should be holding the value of the array right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Just tested some things :) updated my answer.

Trying to store objects as keys in a hash would default to [object Object] because there's no direct way to serialize an object there, but when the key is an array it serializes it to a string first.

Comment: By serializing it, you mean the key becomes the hash value of the string version of the array?

Comment: Whatever you use as property name for an object is converted to a string first. Objects are not maps, they are more like records.